# vaadin multiple date picker

Tags: vaadin

I'm really new to vaadin and am trying to create a date picker in which a user can select multiple days, with each selected date rendered in a highlight color, much like the date picker from doodle.

I started out using the InlineDateField, but am not getting anywhere.
Can it be done with standard vaadin components?
Licensed, non-free vaadin components are not an option, because this solution is for a non-commercial project with 0 budget.

Comment: after more research it looks like I can do something with table, cellstyling and container datasource

Answer (score 0):

And what about to take current implementation of [datefield](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.datefield.html) and make your own implementation? So you extend this class and change the JavaScript? You can inject your JavaScript with changed functionality... and handle the changes in your extended datafield class.